# How to activate the cursor once we deactivated by activating panning tool

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

We have activated pan tool on canvas using the following command:

```
canvasPressEvent(self,event):
   if event.button == 1:
       qgis.utils.iface.actionPan().trigger()
 canvasReleaseEvent(self,event):
   if event.button == 2:
      print "hello"
```

the problem is that it is not at all going to the canvasrelease event. So i want the cursor to be active to draw a line when right click is pressed after activating pan tool how can i do that using python programmin?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your method name. Use canvasReleaseEvent and see if it fixes your problem

Comment: are you creating a new custom map tool in python?

Comment: yes @vinayan after i trigger pan tool when i press right click i want the cursor to be active to draw the line